# I keep getting HttpGet Again and Again

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, view

My problem is i have a login page, it is very simple, I am getting the username and password. I am controlling it at server side. I am using javascript delivering data View to Controller. But the problem is it always sends me to same page. I am always entering the userName and password, but the data even when its correct, there is not a  redirect.

My View Code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Yelken Otel Rezervasyon Kontrol Sistemi</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Login() {
            var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/RezervasyonTalepleri/Giris',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'userName': userName,
                    'password': password
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    location.href = '/RezervasyonTalepleri/Denetim';
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="login-page">
        <div class="form">
            <form class="login-form">
                <input id="userName" type="text" placeholder="username" />
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
                <button id="btnLogin" onclick="Login()" >login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller Code,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Giris()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Giris(string userName, string password)
{
    if(userName=="admin" && password == "123")
    { 
        return Json(new { status = "success" });
    }
    else
    {
        return JavaScript("Yanlış Kullanıcı Adı veya Şifre Girdiniz.");
    }
}
```

I expect that when i enter the right userName and password, it should redirect me to `/RezervasyonTalepleri/Denetim` but it always redirects me to `/RezervasyonTalepleri/Giris`.

Comment: You are probably not login correctly or you need to remove a cookie.  First try to clear IE History using your browser manually.  If this doesn't work I would recommend using fiddler to capture results for debugging.  If you can login using an IE then compare fiddler results between IE and your application.   Usually the issue is with the HTTP headers in the 1st request message.

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, so making an ajax call and then redirecting is pointless. Just do a normal submit and redirect in the POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery library for example included it as below:

```
<title>Yelken Otel Rezervasyon Kontrol Sistemi</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ...
```

Comment: If this was the case, the AJAX would never execute -- but why would the page reload? He seems to have a button in the form, but not a submit element -- so the form would not be submitted, would it?

Comment: When he hit login the login function will call successfully, but because he didn't include JQuery library he will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined` and the form will submit to the same page

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly,

The `success` function is called when the invocation of the Giris Action was successful and not when you return success as `status`.

In your example, you need to check if `msg.status` is equal to `success` and you are ready to go.

So your `success` function would be

```
success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.status === 'success')
                {
                    location.href = '/RezervasyonTalepleri/Denetim';
                }
            }
```